# Adding custom text / notes to a date picker

Tags: android, datepicker

[image]

How can we add **custom notes** on android date picker, im already search in so many web for this problem

Comment: maybe this is custom layout having `Date Picker`, `Button` and `TextView`.

Comment: Create a custom view including CalendarView + Button + TextView and use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simple example of layout that you can do.Just open it in a dialog and work with data you get from calendar.Or you can try to make your personal date picker , this is your choice.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <CalendarView
                android:id="@+id/calendarView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Submit" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Here we have some notes" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: This]

Comment: how to use, in what sense?, how to make it in a dialog or how to read data from calendar?, please explain your problem